# Transparent RelativeLayout which sits "on top" of a surfaceview?

Tags: android

I've got a canvas drawn (I have to keep the canvas, it's doing other things). I'm drawing N amount of images in this canvas, I'm wondering how would I make them clickable? also does anyone know how I could test if a bitmap is in a certain co-ord? Alternatively how would I create a button which was an image on a canvas? or even, How would I create a Transparent RelativeLayout on top of a Surfaceview?

edit.. anyone?? I'm thinking Relative Layout on top of Surfaceview would be the best way to go!

edit2: Setting things to transparent seems to just set the background to black and not actually let me see the Surfaceview I have defined under it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's already transparent and setting it to transparent just makes it black! you also just use bringtofront(); in order to make it sit "on top" of anything.